# alternative to using arrow function in render with same effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using the [react-custom-scrollbars library](https://github.com/malte-wessel/react-custom-scrollbars) and am changing the `zIndex` and other css properties of the scrollbar.

This is working, however, I am getting warnings as I am using an arrow function in my render method. The library's documentation explains that to carry this out to use an arrow function in the render method. [As you can see here there has been an issue raised for this](https://github.com/malte-wessel/react-custom-scrollbars/issues/74), but this has not been updated in the documentation.

I am having difficulties understanding how to implement the following behavior without using arrow functions in render.

```
render(){

  <Scrollbars renderThumbVertical = {({
      style, ...props }) =>
       <div { ...props} style = {{
        ...style,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
        zIndex: 10000,
        borderRadius: 2
      }}/>
  }>
     <p>Content here</p>
     <p>Content here</p>
     <p>Content here</p>

   </Scrollbars>

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply define render thumb function outside of render method and then pass it to props:

```
function renderThumbVertical({ style, ...props }) {
  return (
    <div { ...props} style = {{
      ...style,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
      zIndex: 10000,
      borderRadius: 2
    }}/>
  )
}

// and use it in component
render() {
  return (
    <Scrollbars renderThumbVertical={renderThumbVertical}>
       <p>Content here</p>
       <p>Content here</p>
       <p>Content here</p>
    </Scrollbars>
  )
}
```

Thumb renderer could also be an instance method. If so you can pass it as `this.renderThumbVertical`. However if you need to access `this` inside that method don't forget to bind it in constructor or use class properties.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend declare methods as a class property. Then the methods will be created only once. http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render(){
         return (
           <Scrollbars renderThumbVertical={this.renderThumbVertical}>
             <p>Content here</p>
             <p>Content here</p>
             <p>Content here</p>
           </Scrollbars>
        );
    }
    renderThumbVertical = () => {
         // code
    }
}
```